# Conditional row count across 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function that works fine.  Is there a better way to do it and will this be efficient if I have 100+ rows returned from each table?

**The database**

**Tables**

- `wcx_articles`
- `wcx_videos`
- `wcx_apps`
- `wcx_links`

**The corresponding _active column for each table**

- `article_active`
- `video_active`
- `app_active`
- `link_active`

`_active` is a switch 1 or 0

**This is my current function**

```
public function findInactiveItems() {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = '0'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = '0'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM wcx_apps WHERE app_active = '0'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM wcx_links WHERE link_active = '0'
    ";
        if( $this->num_rows( $query ) > 0 ) {    
            $count = $this->num_rows($query);
            return $count;
        }
    }

 public function num_rows( $query ) {
    $query = $this->link->query( $query );
    if( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ) {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $query, 'Fatal' );
        return mysqli_error( $this->link );
    }
    else {
        return mysqli_num_rows( $query );
    }
    mysqli_free_result( $query );
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with working code

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/55372/9357)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### SQL

If you want a count, ask for a count.  Don't ask the server to send all the data for all the rows, just to have the client count the rows.  (A few hundred rows is a trivial amount of data for a database to handle, but still, you should follow good practices.)

```sql
SELECT SUM(inactive_count) AS inactive_count
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(article_active) AS inactive_count
            FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = '0'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(video_active)
            FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = '0'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(app_active)
            FROM wcx_apps WHERE app_active = '0'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(link_active)
            FROM wcx_links WHERE link_active = '0'
    ) AS wcs_objects;
```

### Schema

If in fact all four of your tables are union-compatible with each other, then you should strongly consider merging them into one table with a `wcx_type` attribute that declares what type of object that row represents.

Are your `…_active` columns really strings?  Those columns should be of the [`BOOLEAN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) (i.e., `TINYINT(1)`) type.  The query should be adjusted accordingly: use `…_active = 0` instead of `…_active = '0'`.

### PHP

You reused the `$query` parameter to store the result of the query.  Don't be stingy like that — it's confusing.  Use a new variable to store the result.

You have a leak: `mysqli_free_result( $query );` never gets called, because that statement is unreachable.

You are mixing the object-oriented and procedural styles of [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli).  You should either use the object-oriented style consistently…

```
public function num_rows($query) {
    if (!($result = $this->link->query($query))) {
        $this->log_db_errors($this->link->error, $result, 'Fatal');
        return $this->link->error;
    }
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $result->free();
    return $num_rows;
}
```

or use the procedural style consistently…

```
public function num_rows($query) {
    if (!($result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query))) {
        $this->log_db_errors(mysqli_error($this->link), $result, 'Fatal');
        return mysqli_error($this->link);
    }
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $num_rows;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned: when using the `COUNT(*)` query, you no longer want `mysqli_num_rows()` or `$result->num_rows`. Rather, you should ask for the `inactive_count` of the first row of the result.

Comment: Hmm Undefined index: inactive_count, should i use a straight query on this and return a result

Comment: Works for me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/03d95/1)

Comment: Yeah it works for me in `phpmyadmin` `SQL`, my php must be wrong, im trying to get the `$row['inactive_count']` from an `assoc array`

Comment: This works but is it right? `$row = $this->get_results($query);
$sum = $row[0];
foreach($sum as $sum) {echo $sum;}`

Comment: I suggest that you ask a [follow-up question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).