# Outputting results from a conditional row count across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli

Follow up question for: [Conditional row count across 4 tables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55318/conditional-row-count-across-4-tables)

After getting some excellent help from 200_success, i managed to output the `SUM()` total of my query using the following code:

`get_results` returns standard `mysqli_assoc_array`:

```
$row = $this->get_results($query);
$sum = $row[0];
 foreach($sum as $sum) {
    echo $sum;
}
```

Is this the best way to handle the result, are there any drawbacks / performance hits to doing it this way, how would you handle this querys result?

**Query**

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(inactive_count) AS inactive_count
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(article_active) AS inactive_count
        FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(video_active)
        FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(app_active)
        FROM wcx_apps WHERE app_active = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(link_active)
        FROM wcx_links WHERE link_active = 0
) AS wcx_objects";
```

Comment: Can you run your query? Seems like it's missing `GROUP BY` clauses which I thought were needed when you are selecting an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`...

Comment: The query works fine, "SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc. are aggregate functions that requires you to specify a GROUP BY, unless you're using them on every column in your SELECT-list" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19222737/3754261

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/03d95/1 - Fiddle by 200_success

Answer (score 5):

**MySQL**

Your query looks fine, I'm not sure it could be further optimized of itself. What I would suggest though is to plug it into a stored procedure, and there are a few good reasons to do this.

1. Cleaner PHP script by only having your behavioral code in your script while just calling the procedure from there.
2. Easier to modify, e.g., if you found yourself using this SQL script in multiple PHP scripts and you had to make a change to it, you would have to change it everywhere, as opposed to just changing the stored procedure once.
3. Better SQL optimization. The way you have it now, every time you run the PHP script it sends an ad-hoc request to the SQL engine and it has to figure out the optimization each time. By storing the SQL script in the RDBMS the engine will optimize it ahead of time, so it will respond quicker each time.

**Create procedure**

You can run this just once:

```
DELIMITER |    
CREATE PROCEDURE wcx_objects() AS    
BEGIN    

SELECT SUM(inactive_count) AS inactive_count
FROM (    
    SELECT COUNT(article_active) AS inactive_count    
        FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = 0    
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT COUNT(video_active)    
        FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = 0    
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT COUNT(app_active)    
        FROM wcx_apps WHERE app_active = 0    
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT COUNT(link_active)    
        FROM wcx_links WHERE link_active = 0    
) AS wcx_objects;    

END|    
DELIMITER ;
```

**Call Procedure in PHP**

Then from PHP all you need to do to get your result set is write this:

```
$query = "CALL wcx_objects();"
```

Comment: I have never heard of a `stored procedure` and googling has come back with some very interesting info, list of pros and cons here http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843 I work a lot with `functions / classes` and will probably build a function that does the same thing as my above code with the ability to pass in variables making it reusable for other `SUM()`'s. Just out of interest where would i place this `procedure` if i wanted to call it in a `function` within a `class`, does it need a separate file?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP but from my understanding you could call it from anywhere in your PHP script where you would otherwise write your whole SQL query. As far as storing it, it's stored in the RDBMS itself at this location: `yourdatabasename.information_schema.routines`

Comment: Oh, wow looking at `phpmyadmin` i can see it has an `add routine` button that allows you to create a `procedure / function`, that is very interesting indeed and something i will experiment with, thankyou

Comment: Cool. I have a tendency to lean towards letting SQL do as much of the data crunching as possible, since it's what it does best, but I'm biased because I'm a SQL programmer. As they say, when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail lol.

Comment: Haha, indeed, I rely on php too much I think, MySQL can do a lot more than I realised and it's something I need to put more time into, thanks for the inspiration

Comment: I'm not convinced that a stored procedure is justified for such a simple query. If you wanted to optimize the SQL, you would be much better off merging the four tables as I [suggested](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55324/9357), as well as ensuring that indexes are in place for the `active` column(s).

Comment: Yeah a stored procedure for this is overkill but good to know they exist. There is a reason why I can't merge the tables, although that would be the ideal solution it just isn't viable, in future I need to learn to design my databases and workout any relations that will be needed beforehand, thanks again for your help on this